# How To Use Variables Down A Promise Chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using nodejs with express framework and mongodb/mongoose to store my data.

I have a register function which does 4 things. Creates a user, creates a token, assigns the token to the user and finally sends an email.

I initially did this using callbacks which worked fine. Im trying to use promises now i have required bluebird to do this. However when one promise is complete i need to use that returned variable in the next promise.

**Register Function**

```
module.exports.register = function(req, res) {

    var input = req.body;

    var newUser = new User ({

        username: input.username,
        email: input.email,
        password: input.password,
        active: false

    });

    var promise = newUser.save();

    promise.then(function(user) {

        return createToken('new', null, user._id);

    }).then(function(token) {

        user.tokens.push(token._id);

        return user.save();

    }).then(function(user) {

        //Do Email Stuff

    }).catch(function(err) {

        return res.json("Could Not Register");

    });
}
```

**Create Token Function**

```
var createToken = function(type, expiry, userid) {

    var token = uuid.v4();

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var newToken = Token({

            type:type,
            token: token,
            expiry: expiry,
            user: userid

        });

        var promise = newToken.save();

        promise.then(function(token) {

            resolve(token);

        }).catch(function(err) {

            reject(err);

        });

    });

};
```

So where im doing "user.tokens.push" it can't find the user. ive read in bluebird that i can use somethign called binding? and then use "this". Could anyone show me how to do this properly.

Also if there is an an error in each promise i'd like the catch method to be dynamic. Instead of just "Could not register" it would be "Could Not Save User" or "Could Not Save Token" depending on which promise failed.

And if theres a way to make this even cleaner let me know.

Comment: You're referencing user.tokens.push but there's no user variable in your code sample. Maybe the example is incomplete or you forgot to retrieve the users?

Comment: @shershen - I think you've identified the point of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no shame in using a var in the scope of the register function to store the value of `user` for later use

```
module.exports.register = function(req, res) {
    var input = req.body;
    var newUser = new User ({
        username: input.username,
        email: input.email,
        password: input.password,
        active: false
    });
    var sUser; // store user in this var
    newUser.save()
    .then(function(user) {
        sUser = user; // save value user to use later on
        return createToken('new', null, user._id);
    }).then(function(token) {
        sUser.tokens.push(token._id); // sUser is user, huzzah
        return sUser.save();
    }).then(function(user) {
        //Do Email Stuff
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // use the content of err to return a meaningful error
        return res.json("something more meaningful based on the content of err");
    });
}
```

You should also avoid the new Promise antipattern in createToken

```
var createToken = function(type, expiry, userid) {
    var token = uuid.v4();
    var newToken = Token({
        type:type,
        token: token,
        expiry: expiry,
        user: userid
    });
    return newToken.save();
};
```

That produces an identical result to your code

another way would be to send `user` to the createToken function and rewrite your code like this

```
module.exports.register = function(req, res) {
    var input = req.body;
    var newUser = new User ({
        username: input.username,
        email: input.email,
        password: input.password,
        active: false
    });
    newUser.save()
    .then(function(user) {
        return createToken('new', null, user);
    }, function(err) { // optionally change errors to meaningful error messages
        throw "newUser.save failed";
    }).then(function(user) {
        //Do Email Stuff
        // you could throw "email failed" if there's an error
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // err could be "newUser.save failed", "newToken.save failed", "email failed"
        // use the content of err to return a meaningful error
        return res.json("something more meaningful based on the content of err");
    });
}

var createToken = function(type, expiry, user) {
    var token = uuid.v4();
    var newToken = Token({
        type:type,
        token: token,
        expiry: expiry,
        user: user._id
    });
    return newToken.save()
    .then(function(token) {
        user.tokens.push(token._id);
        return user.save();
    }) // you could add the following to make the errors suited to you
    .catch(function(err) {
        throw "newToken.save failed";
    });
};
```

Comment: Ive noticed uve opted not to recommend bluebird bind function? Why is this?

Comment: No reason. Just using pure js because i can

Comment: Is there a way i can set what the err value might be in each then promise? Also would you use promises over callbacks all the time? I have the opinion that both ways look pretty horrible

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you could set `err` to whatever you want. re: Promise vs callback, personally, I don't prefer one over the other

Comment: So you're saying i can add "function(err) {} to each then to set the err message. Do you know any detailed article on this as i don't think i fully understand how to throw errors. When you throw does that get returned in the catch as the err variable?

Comment: Right, so do you code using callbacks or promises? It's stopping me from moving forward because im concentrating too much on writing a piece of code i like, i'd like to know what the standard is.

Comment: the only standard I follow is to use the right tool for the task at hand ... if you're more comfortable with callbacks, and there's no promises in your code at all (including library calls) then use callbacks until you get a good handle on promises, then use promises if they are the best solution to the task ... and yes, what you `throw` ends up being the value of `err` in the subsequent catch